# terraform Error no matching subnet found for vpc with id

Tags: terraform

terraform version: 1.0.8

code:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend   = "s3"
  workspace = "**********"
  config = {
    bucket         = "**********"
    key            = "**********"
    region         = var.aws_region
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "**********"
  }
}

data "" "database" {
  depends_on = [data.terraform_remote_state.vpc]
  vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
}
```

result

```
╷
│ Error: no matching subnet found for vpc with id vpc-*********************
│
│   with data.aws_subnet_ids.database,
│   on main.tf line 13, in data "aws_subnet_ids" "database":
│   13: data "aws_subnet_ids" "database" {
│
╵
ERRO[0020] Hit multiple errors:
```

I've searched high and low does anyone have any guidance on why I would be getting this error? All the resources I look at say that it's because aws_subnet_ids was missing the depends_on which I've added in but I'm still having the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to the error message, the vpc has no subnets.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue, I forgot to include the provider in my code